# Readme HTML files in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I am creating a sample C# project to demonstrate some patterns. Along with the project, I'd like to include a "Readme.mht" which contains an overview of the sample, some diagrams, and instructions for how to test it.

1. When the project is opened in Visual Studio, I would like this file to appear.
2. By default, MHT files currently appear in the text editor view. I would like it instead to open using Visual Studio's inbuilt web browser.

I seem to recall project templates in Visual Studio which did just this, but I cannot find any. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicate the test project template, which forces that stupid text file in your face.

Answer (score 1):

A year and a hallf later I stumble on this page:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364046(VS.80).aspx

It's as simple as:

```
<ProjectItem OpenInWebBrowser="true"
```